# How to download ALL artifacts in a gitlab pipeline despite needs

Tags: gitlab-ci

The example below uses [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to start the second_job after the first_job. However, second_job no longer has access to the artefact of the pre_job. Obviously we could add `needs: [pre_job, first_job]`, but there are multiple jobs in the `.pre` stage and we want to download all of their artifacts (without knowing which jobs are run exactly).

Is there a setting, where `needs` only affects the job order, but not the artifact downloading?

```yaml
pre_job:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - touch pre.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pre.txt

first_job:
  stage: check
  script:
    - touch first.txt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - first.txt


second_job:
  stage: check
  script:
    - cat pre.txt
  needs:
    - first_job
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you can do this if you know every possible job that can run in the pre-stage by using the [needs: optional](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsoptional) keyword. You will need to list every job which you may needs artifacts from as an optional dependency.

Example:

```
second_job:
  stage: check
  script:
    - cat pre.txt
  needs:
    - job: first_job
      artifacts: true
    - job: pre_job
      artifacts: true
      optional: true
    - job: other_pre_job
      artifacts: true
      optional: true
    - job: another_pre_job
      artifacts: true
      optional: true
     ... <etc> ...
```

If you are able to define every possible job which you may need artifacts from then this will allow `second_job` to be conditionally dependent on every job defined in needs since the `optional` keyword allows the job to not exist.

In the example above, if a pipeline is triggered with the jobs `first_job` and `other_pre_job` then the `second_job` will wait for both of the previous jobs to complete and receive artifacts from them.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. seems like this is not possible at all :/

> When a job uses needs, it no longer downloads all artifacts from previous stages by default, because jobs with needs can start before earlier stages complete. With needs **you can only download artifacts from the jobs listed in the needs configuration**.

from https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsartifacts